Actual execution time on real hardware
I am trying to calculate the actual execution time on real HW. We have access for IBMQ systems.
What I am thinking is that to find the actual execution time on real HW so that we can know whether our quantum circuit violates or not violates the T1 and T2 time of the Real HW.
Are there any APIs for doing this?
Any help or suggestion in the right direction would be great help for us.

You could use schedule to see execution time, pass a tranpiled circuit to schedule it.
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService
from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager
from qiskit import schedule

service = QiskitRuntimeService()

backend = service.backend('ibm_brisbane')
properties = backend.qubit_properties(range(backend.n_qubits))

qr = QuantumRegister(1)
qc = QuantumCircuit(qr)

qc.sx(0)
qc.measure_all()

pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(backend=backend, optimization_level=1)
isa_qc = pm.run(qc)

scheduled_circuit = schedule(isa_qc, backend=backend)
circuit_duration = scheduled_circuit.duration * backend.configuration().dt

print("execution time {:}[ns]".format(circuit_duration*1000*1000*1000))
print("t1             {:}[ns]".format(properties[0].t1*1000*1000*1000))
print("t2             {:}[ns]".format(properties[0].t2*1000*1000*1000))

scheduled_circuit.draw(backend=backend)

D0 is first drive, M0 is first measurement.


Thank you @taketoshi kinoshita for the response. But this code will only calulate the expected or theoretical execution time. Now, how  to know how much actual time is taken to execute circuit on quantum HW?

From your comment, it seems metrics might be what you're looking for, but when I checked an execution time of the stated job in the answer from the timestamps, 'running' and 'finished', the time was much bigger than what was expected. I might have done something wrong with that metrics, but it looks to me the estimation in the answer would be more precise than the api.

Thank you @taketoshi kinoshita for the help. I think, presently very precise answer of execution time cannot be calculated so I accept this as answer.
